The Scope of the Open RAIL++-M License and Discriminatory Law
Stable Diffusion's Large Language Model (LLM) version 2 is released under the Open RAIL++-M License, which includes the stipulation that "You agree not to use the Model or Derivatives of the Model: In any way that violates any applicable national, federal, state, local or international law or regulation" (license text).
Certain anti-LGBT+ laws, such as Russia's federal law 478-ФЗ, prohibit publishing materials depicting homosexual relationships or gender reassignment (summary of Russia's law on Digital Policy Alert).
If a citizen of one of the countries with such laws generated and shared images using Stable Diffusion's model that depict a gay couple kissing (which appears to be in violation of Russia's law), they would apparently be violating the Open RAIL++-M License. If they instead generated and shared similar images using a model built on top of Stable Diffusion's model (for example, via fine-tuning or Lora) that is released under a license without the above restriction (like the MIT License), would they still be violating the Open RAIL++-M License?

How are you supposing  someone could release a derivative model under the MIT license without violating the terms of the original license?

alpaca-lora-7b is an example of a "derivative" (for lack of a better term) model released under the MIT while being based on a non-commercial model (Stanford Alpaca). Based the linked discussion and the current status of the repository, it was apparently determined that the "derived" model could be released under a different license as long as it's made clear that the original model was released under the more restrictive license and that one needs to comply with both.

The RAIL++-M license states, as part of the conditions imposed by the license

Use-based restrictions as referenced in paragraph 5 MUST be included as an enforceable provision by You in any type of legal agreement (e.g. a license) governing the use and/or distribution of the Model or Derivatives of the Model, [...].

This means that creating a model based on Stable Diffusion's model and licensing your model without the use restrictions is already a violation of the RAIL++-M license.
